# Xml parsing problems using xml2js

Tags: javascript, mysql, xml, node.js, xml-parsing

I need to parse huge XML data and insert the values in a mySQL table.

My XML data is in this form,

```
<BMS version="1.0">
<Summaries>
<Summary Booking_strId="CWBL00D7CB8J8U" Booking_lngId="466244159" Trans_lngId="466244159" App_strCode="WEBIN" Event_strType="CT" Trans_dtmBookingStamp="Mon, 30 Jun, 2014 @ 7:00pm" Trans_dtmBookingDate="Mon, 30 Jun, 2014" Trans_dtmBookingTime="7:00pm" Trans_mnyTicketsTotal="7000.0000" Trans_mnyTicketsBookingFee="224.7200" Trans_mnyTicketsDeliveryFee="0.0000" Trans_mnyInventoryTotal="1.0000" Trans_mnyInventoryBookingFeeTotal="0.0000" Trans_mnyInventoryDeliveryFeeTotal="0.0000" Trans_mnyDiscount="0.0000" Trans_mnyTotal="7225.7200" Trans_mnyTicketsTax="0.0000" Trans_mnyTicketNett="7000.0000" Trans_strTicketsTotal="Rs.7000.00" Trans_strTicketsBookingFee="Rs.224.72" Trans_strTicketsDeliveryFee="Rs.0.00" Trans_strInventoryTotal="Rs.1.00" Trans_strInventoryBookingFeeTotal="Rs.0.00" Trans_strInventoryDeliveryFeeTotal="Rs.0.00" Trans_strDiscount="Rs.0.00" Trans_strTotal="Rs.7225.72" Trans_strTicketsTax="Rs.0.00" Trans_strTicketNett="Rs.7000.00" Trans_intTicketsQuantity="2" Booking_strCommitted="Y" Trans_strPaymentReceived="Y" Trans_strPaymentMode="Credit Card/Debit Card" Trans_strPartialCardNo="" Trans_strAlertMail="mantasea@gmail.com" Trans_strAlertMobile="7259179605" Member_lngId="0" Member_strMail="" Member_strName="Customer" Trans_strBarCodeName="CWBL00D7CB8J8U-466244159" Trans_strBarCodeText="CWBL00D7CB8J8U" Trans_strMessage1="" Trans_strMessage2="" Trans_strMessage3="" Trans_strShowBanner="N" Trans_strBannerImage="" Trans_strBannerURL="" Trans_bitSendConfirmationMail="True" Trans_bitSendConfirmationSMS="True" Trans_strTemplate="BookingConfirmation_CT" Trans_bitTPIN="False" Trans_strTPIN="" Trans_strDiscountText="" Trans_strCurrency="Rs." Trans_strPayType="" Trans_strDebtorId="" Trans_strSubDebtorId="" Trans_strKidShirtSize="" Trans_strGuardShirtSize="" Trans_strRaceCat="" Trans_HasETicket="N" Trans_mnyAdditionalCharges="0.0000" Trans_strAdditionalCharges="Rs.0.00" Trans_strData="" Trans_strETicketURL="" Member_strDetails="" Trans_xmlDetails="" Trans_strMergeTPINSMS="N" Venue_strPhoneNo="" Trans_strETicketURLEx="" Trans_strGenerateKioskBarcode="N" Trans_strTPINSMSText="" Trans_strSMSText1="" Trans_strMergeKioskBarcodeWithSMS="N" Trans_strHasInventory="Y" Trans_xmlAddressDetails="" Venue_strApplication="BT" Trans_strQRCodeText="CWBL00D7CB8J8U-ET00022121,10192,05-Jul-2014,19:07"  />
</Summaries>
<SessionOrders>
<SessionOrder Venue_strCode="CWBL" Session_lngSessionId="10192" Venue_strName="Chowdiah Memorial Hall" Venue_strLocation="Bangalore" Event_strName="Ahmad Jamal Live In Concert " Event_strShortName="Ahmad Jamal Live In Conce" Trans_dtmShowStamp="Sat, 5 Jul, 2014 @ 7:00pm" Trans_dtmShowDate="Sat, 5 Jul, 2014" Trans_dtmShowTime="7:00pm" Trans_strSeatInfo="Row AA to I:C22,C23" Trans_strSeatData="2 X Row AA to I" Cinema_strEmail="" Event_strSKUCode="" Trans_intQuantity="2" Trans_mnyTicketsTotal="7000.0000" Trans_strTicketsTotal="Rs.7000.00" Trans_strTPIN="" Booking_lngId="466244159" Event_strCode="ET00022121" Ticket_strType="T463" AreaCat_strCode="AC00000425" Venue_strLongitude="77.575509" Venue_strLatitude="13.006609" Trans_dtmUTCShowDate="2014-07-05T19:00:00+05:30" Venue_strBuilding="16th Cross" Venue_strStreet="G.D. Park Extension, 2nd Main Road, Malleswaram" Venue_strCity="Bangalore" Venue_strState="Karnataka" Venue_strCountry="India" Venue_strTelephone="39895050" Venue_strPostalCode="560003" Venue_strNameOnly="Chowdiah Memorial Hall" Screen_strName=""  />
</SessionOrders>
<Inventories>
<Inventory TransI_lngId="466244159" TransI_intSequence="1" Trans_intSequence="1" Item_lngId="382" TransI_intQuantity="1" TransI_mnySalesPrice="1.0000" TransI_mnySalesTax1="0.0000" TransI_mnySalesTax2="0.0000" TransI_mnySalesTax3="0.0000" TransI_mnySalesTax4="0.0000" TransI_mnyBookingFee="0.0000" TransI_mnyDeliveryFee="0.0000" TransI_strSalesPrice="Rs.1.00" TransI_strSalesTax1="Rs.0.00" TransI_strSalesTax2="Rs.0.00" TransI_strSalesTax3="Rs.0.00" TransI_strSalesTax4="Rs.0.00" TransI_strBookingFee="Rs.0.00" TransI_strDeliveryFee="Rs.0.00" TransI_strItemIsDeliverable="AV" Booking_strType="" TransI_strData="" TransI_dtmDateTime="30 Jun 2014 7:01 PM" TransI_xmlDetails="" Item_strShortName="Book A Smile Rs 1" Item_strDescription="Book A Smile Rs 1" Item_strTagLine="Book A Smile Rs 1" ItemGroup_lngId="109" Item_strType="DN" TransI_mnyTotal="1.0000" TransI_TransTotal="Rs.1.00" ItemVar_intSequence="1"  />
</Inventories>
<SeatInfos>
<SeatInfo Event_strTitle="Ahmad Jamal Live In Concert" Event_strShortCode="AJLC" Trans_dtmShowDate="05-Jul-2014" Trans_dtmShowTime="07:00 pm" Venue_strName="Chowdiah Memorial Hall" Venue_strCode="CWBL" Booking_strCommitted="Y" Trans_strGate="|" Trans_strBay="|" Trans_strFlight="|" Trans_strLevel="|" Trans_strStand="| |" Trans_strEntrance="| |" AreaM_strCategory="|" Trans_strSeatInfo="Row AA to I:C22,C23" Trans_intQuantity="1" Trans_mnyTicketsTotal="3500.0000" Event_strCode="ET00022121" TType_strCode="T463" Session_lngSessionId="10192"  />
</SeatInfos>
<AddChgss/>
</BMS>
```

I have a single SQL table containing all the attributes as columns. I need to parse the data and put all the data into one single mySQL table, also the repeated attributes should be ignored. The XML format cannot be changed. 
I have wriiten a node.js app ad using xml2j I can parse the string but I don't know how to go ahead.

Here is my node.js code,

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var qs = require('querystring');
var redis = require('redis').createClient();
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var count = 0;

app.get('/adminm', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('adminmovies.html');
});

app.get('/admine', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('adminevents.html');
});

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    count = count + 1;
    var body = "";
    req.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        //console.log(body);
        var xml = body;
        var parsed = "";
        parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
            redis.lpush("events", JSON.stringify(result));

        });

        io.emit('count1', count);
    });
});
http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Now I need the data in this format,

```
{name: 'XYZ', age: '21', ....}
```

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think part of the problem is that the XML you have is using attributes for everything. It might be somewhat easier if it used elements. 
Take a look at my https://github.com/imbroglioj/xml-to-es which allows you to specify in a property file how you want your resultant JSON object massaged by promoting child elements or attributes to top-level, etc.  It would be easy to extend the property file and the collapsing function to erase fields or rename them.